# Simultaneous NSDate generation leading to different time intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsdate, gamekit

In a server-client game using bluetooth connectivity (GameKit, specifically, for iOS6 compatibility), 1 or more client devices (iPhone/iTouch) send a timestamp to the server device (iPad) when a button on each client is tapped. i.e. each of the clients calls:

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

...and then sends to the server the value as an `NSData` payload.

When only 1 client is connected, the time being generated and sent to the server is the same as the time of the physical tap. When 2 or more clients are connected, the generated times differ significantly, even if all the clients are tapped at exactly the same time, e.g.

Client 1 and 2 simultaneously tapped:

- client 1 timestamp = 1396974546.558433 (time interval since 1970)
- client 2 timestamp = 1396974551.274747 (time interval since 1970)

i.e. client 2 is somehow 5 seconds out from client 1. While I'd accept a few milliseconds of difference since truly simultaneous tapping is hard, multiple seconds is unacceptable. Adding additional clients generates a more or less random difference in times, but usually several seconds.

To make things even more mysterious, the timestamps are being generated differently *on the client*: the timestamps being received at the server are the same as those being generated by the client (i.e. it's not something happening in transit or on receipt).

I'm at a loss for what's causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Go to the home screen on both clients and watch the Clock app icon. Are the second hands in sync or are they off by 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` is relative to the time that's set on the device, so you can't rely on two devices sending the same time to your server.

I had a similar issue when developing something using Multipeer Connectivity, and ended up using a library called **[ios-ntp](https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/)** which uses time information from multiple NTP servers along with the latency of the request itself to derive the accurate time. It's worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the devices are, for whatever reason, off by 5 seconds apart

my reason for saying this is that the

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

usually has sub millisecond accuracy

Comment: Yep, you're right. As per ChrisH's answer, time clocks on the devices weren't sync'd. I used ios-ntp to shrink the gap, although it's not perfect.